# How do I fix a chrome bathroom faucet compromised by toilet bowl cleaner

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink

I used toilet bowl cleaner and a toothbrush and it started to turn like this. is there something I can use to fix it. I don't know what to do,

I need help,  I think this is a chrome faucet I don't know for sure.

How do I fix this.

[image]

Comment: not a DIY fix, but Sodium Hypochlorate(active ingredient in toilet bowl cleaner) reacting with chrome would probably be the culprit. I doubt there's a common reversing reaction to fix the smudges as a result.

Comment: Looks like tarnish but it could have been damaged (thin layer of chrome compromised) by the chemicals in the cleaner. Try brasso or a silver tarnish remover.

Comment: Replace the counter top with a marbled one and tell people you got a marbled faucet to match?

Comment: You can have it replated, or you can spend a good deal less replacing it with a new one. And don't use toilet bowl cleaner on anything that *isn't* a toilet bowl. Or get any closer to it than a long-handled toilet brush. It's nasty stuff. I try to clean often enough that plain dish soap (washing up liquid) does the job.

Comment: If the chrome isn't etched you might be able to polish it out.  Go to a higher end automobile place and get some good chrome polish.  If it is etched then your only plan of action would be as Ecnerwal said and get it replated (expensive and pointless for a tap) or get a new one (recommended).